# JBoss EAP 6.1 JBossws-cxf closing the port

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, cxf, port

I am working respecting the  JAX-WS specification and would like to know if there is any method to close the port.

With the metro WS, I can use this
***((com.sun.xml.ws.Closeable) port)***;

Is there any need to close the port especially for performance reasons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CXF's port implement the standard java.io.Closeable interface.  Just cast to that and close().

For normal HTTP use case, there really isn't MUCH advantage in doing so.   However, if using WS-RM or JMS or similar, it does allow things to be disconnected and such sooner.